# Column Not found :android.database.sqlLite.SQLiteException : noSuchColumn : myDate(Code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I was able to insert data in to SQLite table but while retrieving its throwing error, changed database version and all below is my error

```
public String[] GetTotalFifteenDayRAnge() {
        ArrayList<String> objArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor objCursor = objDatabase.query(Constants.TotalByRange, new String[]{"myDate"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        //  Cursor objCursor= objDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT myDate FROM  TotalByRange ",null);
        while (objCursor.moveToNext()) {               
            objArray.add(objCursor.getString(objCursor.getColumnIndex("myDate")));
        }
        return (String[]) objArray.toArray(new String[objArray.size()]);
    }
```

when I tried that raw query its not throwing error but no data in it.Below is the code which I have used for inserting

```
public void InsertTotalCaloriesByRange(double id, String myDate) {
        ContentValues objContentValues = new ContentValues();
        objContentValues.put("Id", id);
        objContentValues.put("myDate", myDate);

        objDatabase.insert(Constants.TotalByRange, null, objContentValues);

    }
```

Exact error is  : "android.database.sqlLite.SQLiteException : noSuchColumn : myDate(Code 1) : , while compiling : select myDate FROM TotalByRange"

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app. Do this every time you change your database structure.

Comment: Why do you think you were able to insert, if you didn't use `insertOrThrow()`?

Comment: @BobMalooga I have unistalled manytimes but no use , actually I have many tables around 5 ...same kinda code I'm using which is working ..

Comment: @CL I think objDatabase.INSERT too works because I have been using from long time

Comment: You are referencing a non existing column. This usually happens when you add a column after the first run (you alter the database structure). Or you misspell a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, actually I thought of pasting the create syntax here , then I realized mistake in create syntax where I missed comma "," before the last column i.e myDate.... but still wonder how I didn't get error while inserting ..anyway thanks